Bridged network with ips not in the same subnet
My problem:
I aim to configure multiple guest machines managed by libvirt to connect to a single bridge. These guests must utilize IP addresses provided by my hosting provider, which may not belong to the same subnet and appear seemingly random. I am facing challenges in establishing proper routing.
Actions Taken:
On each guest system, I configured the gateway to match the gateway employed by the host system (10.0.0.1 provided by the provider).
Each guest system has a static IP.
All qemu processes are connected to my bridge (br0).
My NIC is ens3, with br0 as its master.
br0 possesses one IP address, which is the primary IP address of the host system.
I attempted to establish static routes using the command ip r a <guest ip> dev br0 However, I am unable to ping guest systems from either the host system or external machines.
Condensed Problem Statement:
How can I connect multiple guest systems to a single bridged network where the guest system IPs do not belong to the same subnet?
Outputs:
ip a on host system:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:11:0e:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp0s3
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe11:ead/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

19: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 9a:c7:ba:d4:ce:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet <host ip>/32 scope global br0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::98c7:baff:fed4:ce56/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
81: vnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:16:48:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe16:48ec/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip r on host system
default via 10.0.0.1 dev br0 
10.0.0.1 dev br0 scope link 
<guest ip> dev br0 scope link 

ip a and ip r on guest system


10.0.0.1 isn’t an IP address in a range that exists outside of an intranet. It cannot be assigned by a provider.

@Ramhound: Of course it can; the provider's network is an intranet. Look at the tons of CGNAT-using ISPs. And all of the major 'cloud VM hosting' providers that use 1:1 CGNAT to implement their 'floating IPs'.
